# Working with OFFSET and SPLIT together to get an array of looked-up cells

Tags: google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I'm unable to get OFFSET to return an array of data in [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XocZ0tkb4jllXEVuJS5eS2i11V1R0YxtfuiT2dkrbVw/edit#gid=0). For example in the same sheet, I have a player table which eats an animal, the eats column stores the index of the animal. I want to add up all weights.

[image: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XocZ0tkb4jllXEVuJS5eS2i11V1R0YxtfuiT2dkrbVw/edit#gid=0]

This is what I came up with (the example numbers might not be exactly right) but it only works with the first split value:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(OFFSET($H$11,SPLIT(D6,","),0,1,1),0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `User A` is in B2 and your other table is a Named Range (`1`), please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(vlookup(split(C2,","),NamedRange1,3,0)))
```

Comment: I've created an example. Can you update your answer to make it work with this?https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XocZ0tkb4jllXEVuJS5eS2i11V1R0YxtfuiT2dkrbVw/edit#gid=0

Comment: @Zammbi - this appears to answer the question you posed. Why should it work on some data matrix that is not part of the question?

Comment: @Jeeped my example was poor and confusing, I updated the question. 

Thanks pnuts, I got it to work with:
"=ArrayFormula(sum(vlookup(split(D6,","),$F$12:$H$14,3,FALSE)))"